# Access VBA SQL not executing

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've a report with multiple sites where each row in the database is a page.
I've set a macro to print open the report in the print view and added a function
on opening of said report. The idea was to update a value in each row on printing the whole report.
My method:

```
Private Sub Dummy_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "UPDATE dummy" & _
          "SET dummy.printed = TRUE, dummy.printed_at = Now()" & _
          "WHERE dummy.printed = FALSE AND dummy.id = " & Me.dummy_id

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL   
End Sub
```

But this code is never executing.
Am I referencing each dummy_id wrong or is the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put spaces in front of SET and WHERE.